# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in javacv

Tags: android, javacv

I am using javacv library for video recording 
http://code.google.com/p/javacv/
in my project i need to use opencv_highui.cvLoadImage function 
but on this line i am getting error like

11-20 14:58:38.697: D/dalvikvm(7587): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.javacv.recorder-2/libopencv_highgui.so 0x42474478, skipping init
11-20 14:58:38.697: W/dalvikvm(7587): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_highgui;

i am able to use other opencv_core functions

can you please suggest me some solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it adding:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
```

I don't know why but Eclipse didn't do it automatically.

Comment: I got following error,11-21 14:09:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(23824): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gnustl_static: findLibrary returned null,11-21 14:09:45.580: E/AndroidRuntime(23824): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1285]:  1418 cannot locate '_ZSt10unexpectedv'..., Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: It's not finding the library, can you try the answer I gave you in the other question you opened? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113989/exception-intialization-error-javacv/20115503#20115503